# The Way to Combine Many Inequalities

Tags: inequality

Suppose that we have several inequalities:
\begin{align*} A &\geq B \\ A &\geq C \\ &\;\vdots \\ A &\geq Z \end{align*}

Here, we can shorten the inequalities above using $\min$ and $\max$ function like as follows:

\begin{align*} \min(A-B,\;\dots,\;A-Z) &\geq 0 \quad \textrm{or} \\ 
\max(B-A,\;\dots,\;Z-A)&\leq0\end{align*}

I am wondering whether there is any other way to write many inequalities using just one ineqaulity like the minimum and maximum example.

Comment: You could have $A\ge\max(B,...,Z)$

Comment: @PC1 Thank you for the answer. But, That is essentially same thing to the maximum example.

Comment: There is not really a way to shorten, unless your other variables are ordered somehow.

Comment: @PC1 That is an important point. If they are ordered nothing is problematic. But, they are not :(. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @minchul PC1's first comment shows a form that's simpler than yours, and is "*using just one inequality*", as you asked. If what you were looking for is the answer that you accepted, instead, then you should have asked the question differently, because that answer is neither simpler, nor is it using an inequality.

Comment: I have converted my Answer into "InEquality" , though it is "Debatable" whether it is "Simpler" !! It was just a theoretical Exercise , & I am not justifying the usage of that "technique" !! @dxiv

Comment: @Prem Changing it to an inequality does not make it simpler, but it does improve the obfuscation ;-) Seriously now, the problem is not with your answer, but with the lack of clarity in the question about what the end goal really is.

Comment: I agree about the lack of clarity, which is why I started the Answer with the words "Depending" & "Exact Examples" ; @dxiv ; I think there is room for further tweaking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you want, there may be ways to achieve this; You have to give Exact Examples to get Answers.

In general, here is a theoretical (but not Practical !) way to achieve this and get Abominations which are Equivalent :

$A \ge B$ & $A \ge C$

$A - B \ge 0$ & $A - C \ge 0$
$A - B = |A - B|$ & $A - C = |A - C|$
$A - B - |A - B| = 0$ & $A - C - |A - C| = 0$
$|A - B - |A - B|| = 0$ & $|A - C - |A - C|| = 0$

$|A - B - |A - B|| + |A - C - |A - C|| = 0$

With 3 InEqualities:
$|A - B - |A - B|| + |A - C - |A - C|| + |A - D - |A - D|| = 0$

Making it "Simpler" and converting to "InEquality" :
$ \Sigma(|A - x - |A - x||) \le 0 $ where the Summation is over all the given variables, $B$, $C$, .... $Z$, in the given InEqualities.

These Equalities (Abominations!) are Equivalent to the Original Conditions, are not Practical.

We only get Obfuscative Statements rather than the Intuitive Statements !
Use these only when you want Obfuscation !